# (Why) does Tomcat/Java perform better on Linux than on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, linux, performance, tomcat

I just [read this (one) study](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=38377&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+techtarget%2Ftsscom%2Fhome+%28TheServerSide.com%3A+Your+Enterprise+Java+Community%29) in which Tomcat under Linux outperformed Windows.

From your experience, is this generally true? Any deep reason that could explain the performance difference?

Comment: Here is a bit more recent article: http://mediakey.dk/~cc/tomcat-performance-linux-faster-than-windows/

Comment: I agree with the comments (the benchmark is outdated, with an old JVM, some details are unclear) but still, I've never seen a app server running better on Windows than on GNU/Linux (same hardware, same versions, same parameters, OS tuned by Windows and Linux specialists respectively) on *all* benchmarks I've done. You may take that as a free claim but that's my experience (and to be honest, I don't know many clients running app servers on Windows in production).

Comment: @ripper234: yes, it is generally true. Are you interested in uptime numbers too? What about critical security patches requiring a mandatory reboot? (remember that in some environments, rebooting is considered an unreliable way to execute). Windows is a pig, an insecure bloated piece of piggery. Poor OS design, poor scheduling, bad resources deallocation, etc. Remember that under Linux a "kill -9" is *guaranteed* to release all the memory a program is using. Such a thing doesn't exist under Windows. Leaks. So many leaks. Windows is really a mediocre POS: ever noticed the pathetic uptime of SO?

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing such benchmarks can be so informative, then this one is 4 years old.

By the way these differences usually reside in certain choices related to how the operating system manages memory, cache and threads..

Comment: Damn, I just got this on Google Reader and didn't check the date.

Comment: ..and the JVM used. It's also unclear whether they used the `-server` option.

Comment: @Jack: -1, check here: http://mediakey.dk/~cc/tomcat-performance-linux-faster-than-windows/  If you really think Windows server perform as well as Linux than ask yourself where are all the Windows based Oracle DBs and where are all the Windows "top 500" supercomputers.  Linux sure is at ease there ;)

Comment: I didn't say that Windows performs as well as Linux, I think that the opposite is more probable :) I just wanted to point out that this kind of benchmarks must be carefully used as a reference, my answer was operating-system-agnostic

Answer (score 0):

I take any benchmark with a grain of salt.  It's possible to game any comparison.

I find that one key is to try and spot any bias that the person doing the comparison might have.  There was an infamous comparison of the Java EE Pet Store done with .NET several years back.  The group doing the study had been paid by Microsoft.  They didn't do all they could to optimize the Java EE solution, putting it in a bad light.  The results were discredited as a result.

Does WebPerformance.com have any Linux bias?

If not, there are a lot of factors that enter into such a result.  I'd compare all of them carefully, and try to see if I could spot anything important that might have been left out.

Comment: It's indeed unclear what settings were used. Was JVM `-server` option used? Was NIO connector enabled? Both would matter *a lot* on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Few points (mostly speculation):

- Tomcat developed by FOSS on FOSS software, so it is reasonable that it would perform better on FOSS software.
- Linux is better operating system `;-)`

Generally. It depends on fine tuning experience... If you know windows well you'll tune it better for windows and if you know Linux better then...

Comment: These points make no sense or at the least, aren't an explanation

Comment: Actually first is quite valid. For example MySQL and PostgreSQL are known to be more efficient on Linux/Unix because they are tightly oriented for POSIX operating system and optimized from them.